# O Android não reconhece o caminho do SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk

[image: Foto do erro que o Adroid Studio mostra]
Quando acesso os diretórios que são especificados no caminho absoluto, não consigo encontrar a partir da pasta AppData. Mas o caminho absoluto funciona, quando copio e colo na busca.

Como faço para acessar o arquivo do SDK e inserir novamente seu caminho? Ou modificar seu caminho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema selecionando as opções mostradas nos prints abaixo, nessa ordem:

1. sincronizar arquivos locais (print 1)
2. sincronizar os arquivos do Gradle (print 2)

[image: Sincronizar arquivos locais - print 1]

[image: Sincronizar arquivos do Gradle - print 2]